# Hermite Polynomial Integral Limit

Tags: integration, analysis, limits

I'm trying to find the following limit:

$$ \underset{n \to \infty}{\textrm{lim}}
\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{2^n n! \sqrt{\pi}}\ \int_{\sqrt{2n+1}}^{\infty}\textrm{H}^2_n(x) e^{-x^2}dx $$

Where H is a hermite polynomial (the physicist kind).
I'm pretty sure the limit is

$$ \frac{1}{3^{2/3}\Gamma^2(1/3)} $$

This is based on an asymptotic formula using Airy functions.

Any thoughts on how to find the limit?

If it is any help, the limit can also be represented as

$$ \underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\textrm{lim}}\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{2 \cdot n!}\frac{d^n }{dx^n} \left .\frac{\textrm{erfc}\left ( \sqrt{\tfrac{1-x}{1+x}} \sqrt{2n+1}\right )}{1-x}  \right |_{x=0} $$